# How to find class of an dynamic created object by js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element `div` which is created by js, i want to get it class.
I try to `getElementsByClassName('lt-label')`(it works), than i want to check if lt-label has class lt-online and if it true the another block on the page is block.
My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
        var redTags = document.getElementsByClassName('lt-label');
        if (redTags.is(".lt-online")) {
            $("#l-b-wrapper").css({
                'display': 'block'
            });
        };
    };
});
```

But it doesn't work. Where i have mistake?

I give a link only because the html code is big and i can't show my problem full .Site http://www.zemelushka.ru/test/

lt-label - is a right page widget button

## l-b-wrapper - left page widget button

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing native and jQuery, Use jQuery object since `document.getElementsByClassName` will return you `an array-like object` and they don't have jQuery methods

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.lt-label').is(".lt-online")) {
        $("#l-b-wrapper").css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: slight typo, in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You have a really odd mix of native JS and jQuery which is causing the problem.

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of DOMElements which do not have the `is()` method. If you use jQuery to select your elements you can both avoid the problem and shorten your code:

```
$(function() {
    if ($('.lt-label').hasClass('.lt-online')) {
        $("#l-b-wrapper").show();
    }
});
```

Note that if there are multiple `.lt-label` elements found you may need to loop over them, depending on the behaviour you require.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: doesn't work. Paste your code but nothing changes. If i write getElement ant alert inside function(only to test) it works, but $('.lt-label').hasClass - not...

Comment: Could you please add your HTML to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To work with jquery methods you need jQuery Object otherwise you'll get `error: method is undefined`. So, you may also wrap javascript object with jquery like this:

```
if ($(redTags[0]).is(".lt-online")) {
```

Where, redTags is wrapped by jQuery ie. `$()` and we use `[0]` for first element as `getElementsByClassName` result array-like object.

---

But I would choose simply jQuery object while I work with jquery for simplicity:

`$('.lt-label')` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName('lt-label');`

Comment: If i can do it only with document.getElementsByClassName('lt-label')?

Comment: Yes, you can see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you should know jQuery has it's own dictionary of methods and it works only with jQuery objects. And you are trying to bind a jQuery method `.is()` to a dom object which causes in error because `.is()` is available only for jq objects.

So this would do it *(creating a jq wrapper)*:

```
$(redTags).is(".lt-online")
```

and you can shorten it like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var redTags = $('.lt-label');
    $("#l-b-wrapper").css({
        'display': function(){
            return redTags.is(".lt-online") ? "block" : "none";
         }
    });
});
```

---

If you just want to show/hide the element then you can use `.toggle(boolean)` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var redTags = $('.lt-label');
    $("#l-b-wrapper").toggle(redTags.is(".lt-online"));
});
```